# Interpreting Auto correlation results

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, power-spectral-density, autocorrelation

I used xcorr function in Matlab to compute the autocorrelation of my signal. I obtained a graph, which is shown below. How to interpret this? I read that autocorrelation helps in finding the patterns in the data. And i have went through some of the properties of the auto-correlation.

But i am finding difficulty in obtaining information regarding how my input data is correlated with itself. Do i need to compute any other things in order to get this information? How to understand the autocorrelation graph?[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a zoomed-in plot of the two large peaks, around `t=1.4`?

Comment: Yes. I attached it with the question. Please have a look.

Comment: What kind of signal are you analyzing? What "patterns" are you looking for? The autocorrelation basically indicates how similar a signal is to a shifted version of itself...

Comment: I am trying to analyze the noise coming from the table fan. I observed that it is almost a periodic signal. Above one is autocorrelation result of that. I wanted to know what does autocorrelation indicates in case of this signal.